# Entity Framework - fast insert/ update of millions of records

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-6

I need to insert 1.9 million new records into a MySQL database. To use this I'm using C# Entity Framework, but the process seems incredibly slow. At the current rate, it would take several days to process these records.

What am I doing wrong and how do I speed this up?

In the database I have 2 tables: Hashes and Categories. Each hash should be unique and can have multiple categories, with only 1 category being active per hash.

The process that I need to follow is to first check if the hash exist. If it does, then I need to find the current category, deactivate it and add the new one.

The problem is that my `try{ }` statement is taking about 150ms and the block that does `SaveChanges()` takes about 15-30 seconds. So, doing 1.9M records this way will take several days.

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(filepath)))
using (MySQLContext db = new MySQLContext(options))
{
    // Disable auto detect changes
    db.ChangeTracker.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
    int loopCounter = 0;    
    string line;

    // Load up the db tables in memory
    var hashes = db.Hashes.Select(x => x).ToList();
    var category = db.Categories.Select(a => a).ToList();

    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        var matches = Regex.Matches(line, "(?<MD5>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)(?<Category>[0-9])");

        InputHashModel inputHash = new InputHashModel()
        {
            MD5 = matches[0].Groups["MD5"].Value,
            Category = matches[0].Groups["Category"].Value
        };

        try
        {
            // Check if hash already exists
            Hash hash = hashes.Where(h => h.MD5 == inputHash.MD5).FirstOrDefault();

            // If hash doesn't exist - add it
            if (hash == null)
                hash = new Hash(inputHash.MD5);
            else
            {
                // Check if category already exists
                Category category = categories.Where(a => a.Active == true && a.HashId == hash.Id).FirstOrDefault();

                // If it exists - deactivate it
                if (category != null)
                {
                    // If the same category already exists - proceed to next hash
                    if (category.Source == "ThisInput" && category.Category == inputHash.Category)
                        {
                            loopCounter++
                            continue;
                        }

                    category.Active = false;
                    category.DeactivatedTimestamp = DateTime.Now;
                }
            }

            // Add new category
            Category new_category = new Category() { Hash = hash, Source = "ThisInput", Category = inputHash.Category, Active = true);
            db.Categories.Add(new_category);

            // Save changes every 1000
            if (loopCounter % 1000 == 0)
            {
                db.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + e);
        }

        loopCounter++;
    }

    db.ChangeTracker.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true;
    db.SaveChanges();

    Console.WriteLine("Finished");
}
```

Comment: *Don't* use an ORM like EF for this. ORMs are meant to Map Objects to Relational constructs. There are no objects here, but a whole lot of rows. Use your database's bulk import features to load the data. In SQL Server you can use SqlBulkCopy. For MySQL, use [MySQLBulkLoader](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-bulk-loader.html)

Comment: Agreed with @PanagiotisKanavos ...additionally, "...only 1 category being active per hash." probably means you need to add a relationship between the hash and its active category and avoid that lookup all together, in all situations.

Comment: There's no such thing as bulk update either. Bulk loading works because the client can stream changes to the server and the server can apply them with minimal logging. This isn't possible with updates. ETL jobs typically load changes to a staging table, join with the target on a key and update matching rows

Comment: There is a `BulkUpdate()`, but it's third party. Edit: see my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

This is never going to be the fastest method, but at a minimum you need to aviod accumulating all the entities in the change tracker.  EG after each SaveChanges() run

```
    foreach (var e in db.ChangeTracker.Entries())
    {
        e.State = EntityState.Detached;
    }
```

Comment: This won't help. ORMs are simply not meant for ETL, especially not for bulk operations. Instead of taking 100 years the operation will take 99 years. That's why all SQL Server MVPs and team members hate ORMs. Besides the OP already disabled change tracking.

Comment: The only answer here is "don't use an ORM"

Comment: Change Tracking only affects queries.  "instead of taking 100 years the operation will take 99 years."  Just false.  The issue here is not EF _per se_.  EF can insert consistently 1000 or more rows per second with this method, so long as you keep the change tracker under control.  If you don't the cost of change keeps increasing and the effective insert rate goes to zero.  EF won't ever be the fastest method, but for many scenarios (like migrations) it can be acceptable to have a slower, but simple method.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos SQL Server MVPs hate ORMs because developers use them when they should not. ORMs are awesome.

Comment: @AndreMendonca and this is one of those cases

Comment: OP's issue is that "At the current rate, it would take several days to process these records."  because "the block that does SaveChanges() takes about 15-30 seconds".  Not "I need to load this data in the fastest way possible".

Answer (score 0):

I managed to achieve this through the use of the `BulkInsert()` and `BulkUpdate()` functions from [EntityFramework Extensions](https://entityframework-extensions.net/).

I went about it a slightly different way though ...

1. Ingest the new entries into the EF models with the new relationship.
2. Download all the entries from the database to memory.
3. Compare the new entries to the ones from the database with the `.Intersects(myCustomComparer)`. Do that twice to separate unique and duplicate entries into two lists.
4. Download the relationship entries for the duplicate entries only (lookup by ID). Run through the relationship entries and compare - if needs update, add it to a list. If it needs a new entry, add that to a separate list.
5. Update the relationship entries and add the new ones.
6. Bulk insert the unique entries and their relationship entries.

Here's the code for the functions:

```
public class HashMD5Comparer : IEqualityComparer<Hash>
{
 //Products are equal if their names and product numbers are equal.
    public bool Equals(Hash x, Hash y)
{
    //Check whether the compared objects reference the same data.
    if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;

    //Check whether any of the compared objects is null.
    if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, null) || Object.ReferenceEquals(y, null))
        return false;

    //Check whether the hash' properties are equal.
    return x.MD5 == y.MD5;
}

// If Equals() returns true for a pair of objects
// then GetHashCode() must return the same value for these objects.

public int GetHashCode(Hash hash)
{
    //Check whether the object is null
    if (Object.ReferenceEquals(hash, null)) return 0;

    //Get hash code for the Name field if it is not null.
    int hashMD5 = hash.MD5 == null ? 0 : hash.MD5.GetHashCode();

    //Calculate the hash code for the hash.
    return hashMD5;
}
}
public class HashComparer
{
private static Hash[] uniqueHashes;
private static Hash[] duplicateHashes;
private static Hash[] duplicateHashesInDb;

private static void SortHashes(Hash[] hashes)
{
    Hash[] hashesInDatabase;

    // Download hashes from database
    using (MySQLContext db = new MySQLContext())
    {
        hashesInDatabase = db.Hashes.Where(h => h.MD5 != null).ToArray();
    }

    // Find duplicates in database
    duplicateHashes = hashes.Intersect(hashesInDatabase, new HashMD5Comparer()).ToArray();
    duplicatehashesInDatabase = hashesInDatabase.Intersect(hashes, new HashMD5Comparer()).ToArray();

    // Find uniques in database
    uniqueHashes = hashes.Except(duplicateHashes, new HashMD5Comparer()).ToArray();
}

private static void ActionDuplicateHashes()
{
    Assessment[] assessmentsInDatabase;
    List<Assessment> assessmentsToDeactivate = new List<Assessment>();
    List<Assessment> assessmentsToAdd = new List<Assessment>();

    // Download assessments from database
    using (MySQLContext db = new MySQLContext(GenerateMySQLOptions()))
    {
        var duplicateHashIds = duplicateHashesInDb.Select(h => h.Id).ToArray();
        assessmentsInDatabase = db.Assessments.Where(a => duplicateHashIds.Contains(a.HashId)).ToArray();
    }

    foreach (var inputHash in duplicateHashes)
    {
        // Lookup the hash in the database to get the ID
        var liveHashId = Array.Find(duplicateHashesInDb, h => h.MD5 == inputHash.MD5).Id;

        // Find the assessment in the database to compare (and deactive if needed)
        var liveAsssessment = Array.Find(assessmentsInDatabase, a => a.HashId == liveHashId);

        // Get the new assessment of the hash
        var newAssessment = inputHash.Assessments.FirstOrDefault();

        if (newAssessment == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Failed lookup for new assessment {inputHash.MD5}");
            return;
        }
        // Set the hashId (relationship) for the new assessment
        newAssessment.HashId = liveHashId;

        if (liveAsssessment != null)
        {
            if (liveAsssessment.Origin == newAssessment.Origin &&
                liveAsssessment.Category == newAssessment.Category)
            {
                // Exact duplicate - leave as is
            }
            else
            {
                // Deactivate the current assessment in the database
                liveAsssessment.Active = false;

                // Add the assessment to a list to deactive (update)
                assessmentsToDeactivate.Add(liveAsssessment);
                // Add the new assessment that will be added once the old one gets deactivated
                assessmentsToAdd.Add(newAssessment);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // No assessment for the hash in the database - just add a new one 
            assessmentsToAdd.Add(newAssessment);
        }
    }

    // Bulk update the assessments in the database that are to be deactivated
    using (MySQLContext db = new MySQLContext(GenerateMySQLOptions()))
    {
        db.Assessments.BulkUpdate(assessmentsToDeactivate);
    }

    // Bulk insert the new assessments
    using (MySQLContext db = new MySQLContext(GenerateMySQLOptions()))
    {
        db.Assessments.BulkInsert(assessmentsToAdd);
    }
}

private static void ActionUniqueHashes()
{
    // Bulk insert all unique hashes and their assessments
    using (MySQLContext db = new MySQLContext())
    {
        // options.IncludeGraph adds any relationships to the database as well
        db.Hashes.BulkInsert(uniqueHashes, options => options.IncludeGraph = true);
    }
}
}
```

There is more optimisation to be done because this uses A LOT of RAM. A specially when doing the unique hashes bulk insert (not sure why). But all in all it works.